# No underlined letters when pressing ALT on ALT+CTRL+DEL menu in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

I just upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.  On the menu that opens when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does not underline the letters that can be used as keyboard shortcuts.

For example, I used to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>
+<kbd>T</kbd> to jump to Task Manager, but now, <kbd>Alt</kbd>
+<kbd>T</kbd> does nothing.

How can I re-enable these keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't fix your issue per se, but an easy way to open the Task Manager is `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ESC`.

Comment: & just to note that this works right back to XP.